# Selenium & Instagram: Count volume of incoming messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I am currently learning Python and I have been trying to write a program that accesses my Instagram profile and counts the number of incoming / unread messages every time it runs.
So far, I am able to access all the way into my inbox, however I am not sure how I should go from there, with locating the elements and counting them. Tried using BeautifulSoup4 and standard code, but something isn't sticking.

I have tried locating them in HTML, through the blue dot, but it does not really help, as they all share the same div class.

```
<div class=" _41V_T   Sapc9                 Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm                                                                                                              " style="height: 8px; width: 8px;"></div>

new_message = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "_41V_T   Sapc9                 Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm")))
```

Any ideas on how I should go about with this?

[image: New messages]

@Insula, thank you so much for your feedback. My code is as follows, but returns `Unread messages:  0`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, features='html.parser')
new_message = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"Igw0E   rBNOH          YBx95   ybXk5    _4EzTm                      soMvl"})
counter = 0
for i in new_message:
    counter +=1
print('Unread messages: ', counter)
```

The class in HTML would be this:

```
<div class="                     Igw0E   rBNOH          YBx95   ybXk5    _4EzTm                      soMvl                                                                                        "><div class=" _41V_T   Sapc9                 Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm                                                                                                              " style="height: 8px; width: 8px;"></div></div>
```

**EDIT**

Tried numerous variations and the issue persists. However, when running the following, it appears that its locating something, but it comes back empty.

```
new_message = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=="div" and tag.get("class") == "_4EzTm")
if new_message is not None:
print("Found")
else:
print("Failed")
```

Output:

```
Found
Process finished with exit code 0
```

At this point, I am not certain how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

What I have found is, if you dig a bit deeper in the inspect element you will find there is code for the little blue dot what notifies you have a new message:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, I have not received a message from the bottom user, so the blue dot is not showing up.

Then you want to find all of them classes and count them:

```
counter = 0

user = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"Igw0E   rBNOH          YBx95   ybXk5    _4EzTm                      soMvl"})
for tag in user:
    counter +=1

print("Unread messages: ",counter)
```

The class name is probably different for you, you could always find the style which I would recommend as it is more accurate, like so:

```
soup.find_all("div",{"style" : "height: 8px; width: 8px;"})
```

*Height and width could change depending on your browser window, so take that into consideration when using style to locate the element.*

**EDIT:** if it is not working, here are some things you can try:

1. Take out the counter and the other stuff, just print the user and see what it throws out. Like if there is an error or something and try to debug it.
2. Add this following line of code, so that the driver waits until elements are loaded:

   ```
   driver.implicitly_wait(10) #seconds
   ```
3. Make sure the classes you are scraping are correct and static (meaning they do not change each time you load it)
4. Locate some other elements on the page, see if it's the page or your code what is messing it up. Maybe try just locating one of the blue dots (take out the range loop for this), something like this:

   ```
   user = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"Igw0E   rBNOH          YBx95   ybXk5    _4EzTm                      soMvl"})
   print(user)

   if user not None:
      print("Found")
   else:
      print("Failed")
   ```

Comment: this does make a lot of sense and the classes are also the same. The thing though is that, calling soup by itself produces  an error. I have tried `soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)` but then it requires me to use the `features=html.parser` , which also results in an error. The errors respectively are: GuessedAtParserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). In the second scenario, it returns exit error 0, but the print function returns 0 for some reason

Comment: @georgiosan please edit your question with the error you are getting, this should work if you have BeautifulSoup properly installed, thanks.

Comment: hm, that is weird. Double check if you are scraping the right classes. and if you have scraped the classes, move on to the style or vice versa.

Comment: I have tried numerous things but I can only assume that it does not work because its in JS and the divs are dynamically created ...does it work on your end?

Comment: check my edit mate, if that doesn't work i'm afraid i don't know what the problem is.